# C++ multiple char array comparison

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Okay so I am a bit stuck here with an assignment and really have no idea what to do next. The user is suppose input a series of key answers (A-D) and then have multiple students (the amount depends on the users input) input their own answers and the program should compare their answers with the answer key that was previously entered and score each student individually. Now my problem is, how do compare each student's answer with the answer key in the array? Here is my code so far

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int NumOfQ;
    int NumOfS;
    char TestAns[50];
    string StudentNames[50]; 
    int StudentScores[50];
    char StudentAns[50];
    int score[50];

    cout << "Please enter the Number Of Questions\n";
    cin >> NumOfQ;

    cout <<"\nPlease enter your answers\n";
    for(int x = 0; x < NumOfQ; x++){
        cin >> TestAns[x];
    }

    cout <<"\nPlease enter number of students\n";
    cin >> NumOfS;

    cout <<"\nPlease enter Student's Names\n";
    for (int s = 0; s < NumOfS; s++){
        cin >> StudentNames[s];
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < NumOfS; z++){
        cout<<"\nStudent: " << StudentNames[z] << " Please enter your test answers\n";

        for (int a = 0; a < NumOfQ; a++){
            cin >> StudentAns[a];
        }
        score[z] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <=NumOfQ; i++){
        if(TestAns[i] == StudentAns[i]){
                score[z]++;
            }
        }

    }

    for(int Z = 0; Z < NumOfS; Z++){
        cout <<"\Student : " << StudentNames[Z] << score[Z]  << " out of " << NumOfQ << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scoring is very easy - you add one for every match in the answer and the key, like this:

```
int score = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != NumOfQ ; i++) {
    if (TestAns[i] == StudentAns[i]) {
        score++;
    }
}
```

You can do it with even less code if you recall that logical operations return zero for "true" and one for "false".

**WARNING:** This may cost you some readability points among your peers, or even some real points if your professor fails to get impressed by such brevity:

```
int score = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != NumOfQ ; i++) {
    score += (TestAns[i] == StudentAns[i]);
}
```

Case sensitivity is another concern: what if the answer key is `c`, and the user enters `C`? The above code would not give the student his hard-earned points, which is wrong. If you force the case of both characters to upper, mixed-case comparison would be correct:

```
if (toupper(TestAns[i]) == toupper(StudentAns[i])) {
    score++;
}
```

Comment: How can I display which answers were true and false in this IF statement? and thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @ssj3goku878 In the `if` branch, add an output statement that says something like `cout << "Answer " << i << " is correct." << endl;` Add an `else` branch, and write `cout << Answer " << i << " is incorrect." << endl;`

Comment: I'm having another issue if you could help me, the loop that I have right now will loop through every student and ask for their answers until there are no more students, the score variable will keep adding up all those students answers, is there a way to have it ONLY add up each individual student until it runs out of students? these loops are so tricky!

Comment: @ssj3goku878 Yes - put the variable declaration, the loop, and the statement that prints the score together, inside the outer loop on `z`. The score will get reset, then the loop will add `1` for each correct answer, then you'll print the score, and then the score would be forgotten. Alternatively, you can define an array `scores` instead of a single variable `score`, and do `scores[z]++` instead of `score++`.

Comment: Hello, can you look over my code one more time? I tried to add the score[z]++ array just like you suggested and print them out but I am getting some weird numbers in the output :(

Comment: @ssj3goku878 There are two problems: the loop that reads answers needs to close before the loop that computes the scores, and you need to set `score[z]=0;` before going into the score computation loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35878/discussion-between-ssj3goku878-and-dasblinkenlight)

Comment: @ssj3goku878 You placed a curly brace in a wrong spot, did not set `scores[z]` to `0`, and incremented `scores[i]` instead of `scores[z]`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your last 'for' block with:

```
StudentScores[z] = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < NumOfQ; a++){
    cin >> StudentAns[a];
    if (TestAns[a] == StudentAns[a])
        ++StudentScores[z];
}
```